# Can't find null value for: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (solved, caused by Boolean vs boolean)

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

Please help figure out why IntelliJ gives NullPointerException.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   ex3.Horse.about(Horse.java:16)    at ex3.Horse.ride(Horse.java:21)    at
>   ex3.Hippodrome.main(Hippodrome.java:19)

Class Horse:

```
package ex3;

public class Horse {
    String name;
    int speed;
    String color;
    Boolean isMale;
    int age;

    void eat(){
        System.out.println("eating ... ");

    }

    void about(){
        String sex = (isMale) ? "Male" : "Female"; // тернарный оператор
        System.out.printf("name: %s, age: %d, sex: %s", name, age, sex);
    }

    void ride(){
        about();
        System.out.println("riding at speed: " + speed);


    }
}
```

And Class Hippodrome:

```
package ex3;

import java.util.Random;

public class Hippodrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Horse[] horses = new Horse[10];

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < horses.length; i++) {
            horses[i] = new Horse();
            horses[i].name  = "Kon " + i;
            horses[i].age = 1 + random.nextInt(10);

        }

        for (Horse horse : horses) {
            horse.ride();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I think he knows what it is, the issue is figuring out where it occurs :p

Comment: @ACVM correct :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boolean` is a class, and as opposed to the primitive type `boolean`, when used as a field, its default value is `null` and not `false`.

That's why `isMale` will throw a NPE on the line `String sex = (isMale) ? "Male" : "Female";`

As @ACVM noted: You can fix this by initializing `isMale` to `false` or changing its type to `boolean`

Comment: Good catch, the code should probably use the `boolean` primitive type in this case

Comment: Thank you so much! Being new this given me couple of hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: @AlexK You're welcome, if my answer solved your problem you can always mark it as accepted